# Which symbols to avoid when naming AD DS groups?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, best-practices

can somebody point out to the symbols which is better not to use when naming AD DS groups? I want to have some explanations/links to documentation on why those should not be used. For example Windows Server 2012 allows you to use "/" in group name but I believe it may cause issues in certain scenarios as this symbol has a special meaning in LDAP filter specification for example... So certain symbols allowed but may cause interoperability issue I presume. Will appreciate list of symbols to avoid with explanation why/prospective troubles you may run into using them

Comment: Ldap filter has specific escape characters to take into account the "special" allowed characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want interoperability between AD and any system that can ever be connected to it, to be on the safe side use only **alphanumeric characters and underscores** in all names. It doesn't hurt much to avoid spaces and (especially important) **diacritics**. If you do opposite, the problems may arise when you try ie. integrated login with some software, even despite declared (not always well tested) UTF-8 conformance.

A nice example is the Ruckus software for WLAN management that my company uses, which fails on every LDAP logon/group name with diacritics. This includes both *CN* and *sAMAccountName*.

Another example can be UNIX shell scripts, which may not always correctly handle spaces in arguments, or may need specific locales installed to handle diacritics.

Answer (score 5):

Active Directory has been historically compliant to RFC 2253 for naming conventions; I don't think that has changed for Windows 2012 (info about Windows 2003: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776019%28v=ws.10%29.aspx )

The RFC lists the following characters:

```
o   one of the characters ",", "+", """, "\", "<", ">" or ";"
o   a leading space; a trailing space;
```

That list matches what is stated on this other article about Windows 2012 R2: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733146.aspx